# Searching NSArray using suffixes

Tags: objective-c, search, nsarray

I have a word list stored in an `NSArray`, I want to find all the words in it with the ending 'ing'.

Could someone please provide me with some sample/pseudo code.

Comment: Just a word of warning: You may find that asking "Could someone please..." without demonstrating much research effort on your own side may attract negative reactions (downvotes, close votes, etc.) So: What have you done so far to solve the problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`NSPredicate`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSPredicate_Class/Reference/NSPredicate.html) to filter `NSArrays`.

```
NSArray *array = @[@"test", @"testing", @"check", @"checking"];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF ENDSWITH 'ing'"];
NSArray *filteredArray = [array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

Comment: +1 for using a predicate - another good method for filtering an array.

Answer (score 4):

Let's say you have an array defined:

```
NSArray *wordList = // you have the contents defined properly
```

Then you can enumerate the array using a block

```
// This array will hold the results.
NSMutableArray *resultArray = [NSMutableArray new];

// Enumerate the wordlist with a block
[wordlist enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    if ([obj hasSuffix:@"ing"]) {
        // Add the word to the result list
        [result addObject:obj];
    }
}];

// resultArray now has the words ending in "ing"
```

(I am using ARC in this code block)

I am giving an example using blocks because its gives you more options should you need them, and it's a more modern approach to enumerating collections. You could also do this with a concurrent enumeration and get some performance benefits as well.

Answer (score 2):

Just loop through it and check the suffixes like that:

```
for (NSString *myString in myArray) {
  if ([myString hasSuffix:@"ing"]){
    // do something with myString which ends with "ing"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
NSMutableArray *results = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

// assuming your array of words is called array:
for (int i = 0; i < [array count]; i++)
{
    NSString *word = [array objectAtIndex: i];
    if ([word hasSuffix: @"ing"])
        [results addObject: word];
}

// do some processing

[results release]; // if you're not using ARC yet.
```

Typed from scratch, should work  :)